# piping cronjob output to logger prevents it from exiting

Tags: shell, cron, sh

A small example to show my problem. The default shell is `bash` but my scripts use `sh`. This is the crontab line which I added for **root** (`start.sh` has to be run as root):

```
*/1 * * * * "/home/mydir/start.sh" "/home/mydir" 2>&1 | logger
```

Contents of `start.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
nohup "$1"/start_sleeper.sh "$1" &
```

Contents of `start_sleeper.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/python -u "$1"/sleeper.py "$1" >> "$1"/log &
```

`sleeper.py` prints a message every 5 seconds which is appended to `log` in the same directory. It should continue to run in the background while `start.sh` can proceed and then exit. It indeed proceeds with any code below the `nohup "$1"/sta..` line, but it does not exit for some reason:

```
pgrep -lf sleeper.py
22303 /usr/bin/python -u /home/mydir/sleeper.py /home/mydir
pgrep -lf start.sh
22296 /bin/sh -c "/home/mydir/start.sh" "/home/mydir" 2>&1 | logger
```

When I omit `2>&1 | logger` from crontab then `start.sh` exits. Is there any way in this case to pipe output to the logger without `start.sh` remaining opened?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add `/bin/kill -SIGHUP $PPID` at the **end** of `start.sh`. The cronline spawns 2 processes, one for the actual `start.sh` and one for piping output to `logger`. The SIGHUP breaks the 'connection' between these two, thus they will both exit. Seems hacky but I'm out of ideas.

Note that $PPID is not standardly available in all shells.